# Calling jQuery.remove() on a DOM made from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
html = '<h1>foo</h1><p>bar</p>';
virtual_dom = $(html);
console.log(virtual_dom);
// logs a data structure recognizable as a DOM with the h1 and p from the string
```

Does jQuery provide a way to remove paragraphs from `virtual_dom`, such that `console.log(virtual_dom)` will log a DOM with only a `h1` tag, like `$('p').remove()` but affecting `virtual_dom` instead of the actual document rendered by the browser?

Comment: @Stev: `.remove()` doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/N7UPN/1/. May be because the elements are not yet actually in the DOM and as such cannot be removed.

Comment: See post :) going to check your fiddle ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), for example:

```
virtual_dom = $(html).filter(":not(p)");
```

This will *exclude* all `p`aragraphs from your `html`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N7UPN/)**.

Comment: @zerkms: Indeed, much more terse :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your virtual DOM is traversable and each tag nodes are removable.

Test this in FireBug or Browser console

```
var html = $('<div />');
html.append('<p /><p />').children(':last').text('Test');
console.log(html.html());
html.children(':first').remove();
console.log(html.html());
```

Comment: Console.log might not be available through jsfiddle ... use alert instead, here is my fork http://jsfiddle.net/QUWhM/ ... The answer to your question is Yes ! Use remove() method to delete the node permanently :)

Comment: You asked to remove ... filter will only build a new jQuery collection without altering the original virtual_dom tree.